# What distribution am I sampling from?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables with Gaussian joint distribution

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}( 
\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} \end{bmatrix}
).  $$

Furthermore, Assume that $X_2$ and $X_3$ have Gaussian joint distribution

$$ \begin{bmatrix} X_2 \\ X_3 \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}( 
\begin{bmatrix} \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\ \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \end{bmatrix}
).  $$

To my understanding, this does not imply that $[X_1 \ X_2 \ X_3]^T$ has a multivariate Gaussian joint distribution and also does not imply anything about ${\rm cov}(X_1,X_3)$.

Now consider the following method of sampling:

First, let $x_3$ be sampled from $X_3 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_3,\Sigma_{33})$. Then, let $x_2$ be sampled from the conditional distribution $(X_2 | X_3 = x_3) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{2 | 3},\Sigma_{2 | 3})$, where

$$ \mu_{2 | 3} = \mu_2 + \Sigma_{23} \Sigma_{33}^{-1} (x_3 - \mu_3),
\\
\Sigma_{2 | 3} = \Sigma_{22} - \Sigma_{23} \Sigma_{33}^{-1} \Sigma_{32},
$$

which are obtained from the conditional distribution of multivariate Gaussians. If I'm not mistaken, this is equivalent to $[x_1, x_2]^T$ being sampled from $\mathcal{N}( 
\begin{bmatrix} \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\ \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \end{bmatrix}
)$.

Finally, I sample $x_1$ from the conditional distribution $(X_1 | X_2 = x_2) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{1 | 2},\Sigma_{1 | 2})$, where

$$ \mu_{1 | 2} = \mu_1 + \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} (x_2 - \mu_2),
\\
\Sigma_{2 | 3} = \Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \Sigma_{32}.
$$

My question is what distribution is $[x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$ being sampled from? Is it from a multivariate Gaussian of the form $\mathcal{N}( 
\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \\ \mu_3 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & {\rm cov}(X_1,X_3) \\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\ {\rm cov}(X_3,X_1)  & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33} \end{bmatrix})$?  If so, is there some inherent assumption in the method of sampling that defines what ${\rm cov}(X_1,X_3)$ is?

For example, here's $10^5$ samples with $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 = 0$, $\Sigma_{11} = \Sigma_{22} = \Sigma_{33} = 1$, and $\Sigma_{12} = \Sigma_{21} = \Sigma_{23} = \Sigma_{32} = 0.9$:

[image]

Comment: It is being sampled from a (non time homogenous) Markov chain, though not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi Andrew: I think he meant to ask if there a tri-variate joint density that could be sampled from that would results in samples that have the same density as samples  from that conditional sampling scheme he described ? Intuitively, one would think it would be trivariate normal but showing that is a different story since $corr(X_{1}, X_{3})$ is unknown.

Comment: I remember reading this a long time ago and finding it pretty interesting. I don't have time to read it now  but it might be relevant to your question.  http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/GelmanMeng1991